# TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Im trying to make tkinter popups with a image in them, a image from bytes. It works the first time, but when i try to make a second popup after clicking the first one away, it gives the error
`_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist`

this is probably caused because pyimage1 gets garbage collected, i tried storing it in a list but it didn't work

this is my code:

```py
import PIL
import socketio
import json
from tkinter import *
import io
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import threading
import tkinter as tk
tk_image = []

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.event
def connect():
    print('Connected to server')


@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('Disconnected from server')

@sio.on('command')
def command(data):
    cmd_data = json.loads(data)
    reqcmd = cmd_data["command"]
    args = cmd_data["args"]
    flags = cmd_data["flags"]
    try:
        args0 = args[0]
    except IndexError:
        args0 = ""
    try:
        args1 = args[1]
    except IndexError:
        args1 = ""
    try:
        flags0 = flags[0]
    except IndexError:
        flags0 = ""
    try:
        flags1 = flags[1]
    except IndexError:
        flags1 = ""
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    if reqcmd == "popup":
        
            def show_image_popup(image_bytess, argss1):
                try:
                    global tk_image
                    popup = tk.Toplevel(root)
                    popup.title(argss1)
                    popup.geometry("400x400")
                    image = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(bytes(image_bytess)))
                    image = image.resize((400, 400))
                    print(tk_image)
                    if len(tk_image) == 0:
                        tk_image.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
                    else:
                        tk_image[0].paste(image)
                    print(tk_image[0])
                    image_label = tk.Label(popup, image=tk_image[0])
                    image_label.pack()
                    image_label.configure(image=tk_image[0])
                    image_label.image = tk_image
                    popup.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: (image_label.destroy(), popup.destroy()))
                except (Exception, AttributeError) as e:
                    print(e)
                    sio.emit("msg", e)
            if flags0 == "img":
                threading.Thread(target=show_image_popup, args=(flags1, args0)).start()
    root.mainloop()

sio.connect('')
sio.wait()
```

Comment: `pyimageX` is the name that is automatically given to the image. If it is saying it doesn't exist it's because it lost the reference to it. Make sure you store the PhotoImage persistently in something that wont be garbage collected.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy i suspected that might be the reason, so i made it a global variable but that didn't work,

Comment: push it into a list and see if it sticks around. Or use the reference you stored on the other label... When I used to use tkinter procedurally to do stuff like this, I stored all of my images in a global dict. I actually had a special dict that would start out as `{name:path}` and overwrite itself to `{name:image}`

Comment: You could also switch to a class-based style and storing the image on `self.some_var_name` will definitely maintain the reference.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy i updated my script to this:
```
                    print(tk_image)
                    if len(tk_image) == 0:
                        tk_image.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
                    else:
                        tk_image[0].paste(image)
                    print(tk_image[0])
                    image_label = Label(popup, image=tk_image[0])
```
pyimage1 does exist, but at the last line when i create the label it says it doesnt exist

Comment: interesting. Can you post your entire code. I am going to copy/paste/fix it. Just delete your snippets and dump the whole script... or at least everything related to these labels.

Comment: Where are the image bytes stored? I ask, because I opine that you are forcing that situation and you could possibly handle this better if you don't do it that way.

Comment: ive edited the post with the entire script

Comment: The issue is due to multiple instances of `Tk()`.

Comment: Do you create more than one instance of `Tk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to emulate your socket with a button press. It's a poor attempt but the script does work. It sends bytes to the popup, and displays the image, no matter how many times you redisplay. The only thing I see that I am doing differently than you is storing the image in a global dict. I'm also not bothering to store a reference on the `Label`. The label get's destroyed as soon as the window is closed so, storing anything on the `Label` is a waste of time.

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter as tk, random, io

""" fake socket """
socket = {} 
for picpath, name in (('snips/image1.png', 'image1'), ('snips/image2.png', 'image2')):
    with open(picpath, 'rb') as img:
        socket[name] = img.read()

def dosocket():
    name = random.choice(list(socket.keys()))
    show_image_popup(socket[name], name)
""" end fake socket """
                
images = {}
root   = tk.Tk()     
    
def show_image_popup(imgbytes, title):
    global images

    popup = tk.Toplevel(root)
    popup.title(title)
    popup.geometry("400x400")

    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgbytes)).resize((400, 400))
    
    if not (img:=images.get('default')):
        img = images['default'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    else: img.paste(image)
        
    image_label = tk.Label(popup, image=img)
    image_label.pack()

    popup.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: (image_label.destroy(), popup.destroy()))
    
button = tk.Button(root, text='click', command=dosocket)
button.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Edit: I just realized your actual problem. Every time you call `command` you create a new instance of Tk. You need to refactor your code to use ONE and ONLY ONE instance of Tk.

Comment: You can have multiple instances of `Tk` if you always pass in a `master` argument when creating `tkinter` objects.